# Scala Window Partitionby Update Random Record

Tags: scala, random, window, updates

I have following data:

```
group_id    id  name
----        --  ----
G1          1   apple
G1          2   orange
G1          3   apple
G1          4   banana
G1          5   apple
G2          6   orange
G2          7   apple
G2          8   apple
G3          7   banana
G3          8   orange
```

I want to update 1 random record of each group with 1, rest everything should be zero, like this:

```
group_id    id  name   random_pick
----        --  ----   -------------------
G1          1   apple       0
G1          2   orange      0
G1          3   apple       0
G1          4   banana      0
G1          5   apple       1
G2          6   orange      0
G2          7   apple       1
G2          8   apple       0
G3          7   banana      0
G3          8   orange      1
```

My thoughts:

1. Add column with 0 as default value
2. use Window.partitionBy("group_id"), then get count of each group, take random between 1 and the count, update the record to 1

But how in scala?! :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like....

```
case class MyRow(group_id: Int, id: Int, name: String, randomPick: Boolean = false)

val randomPicks = myData.groupBy(_.groupId).toList.flatMap{
  case (_, l) => 
   val h :: t = scala.util.Random.shuffle(l)
   h.copy(randomPick = true) :: t
}
```

Comment: Thank you! As I am new to scala, trying the other solution first.

Answer (score 0):

More verbose than @TerryDactyl

```
case class Tup(groupId: String,
               id: Int,
               name: String,
               randomPick: Boolean = false)

val ts = Seq(
  Tup("G1", 1, "apple"),
  Tup("G1", 2, "orange"),
  Tup("G1", 3, "apple"),
  Tup("G1", 4, "banana"),
  Tup("G1", 5, "apple"),
  Tup("G2", 6, "orange"),
  Tup("G2", 7, "apple"),
  Tup("G2", 8, "apple"),
  Tup("G3", 7, "banana"),
  Tup("G3", 8, "orange")
)

val grouped = ts.groupBy(_.groupId)
val withChosen = grouped.map{case (_, ts) => 
  val l = ts.length
  val i = scala.util.Random.nextInt(l)
  ts.zipWithIndex.map{ case (tup, idx) =>
    if (idx == i) tup.copy(randomPick = true)
    else tup
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new so, I will go with this

1. Can you please tweak the code as if you have dataframe? 
`var df = spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load(i_file)
      .select("groupId", "Id", "name") `
2. `val l = ts.length` ==> this should be somehow group.length?

Comment: 1. I have actually never worked with spark. Your question is a generic one. I would rather leave mine platform agnostic - it would be of more value to others in this format - IMHO. As per 2. yes, that would be the group length

Comment: OK, Thank you @Yaneeve